# How can i get the values for the Vertica database parameters?

Tags: parameters, vertica

How can I get the values for the Vertica parameters

- example :
  In oracle I can do this :
  `sql:>show parameter <parameter_name>`

How can I do this in vertica? And how to alter them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM CONFIGURATION_PARAMETERS;
```

You used to be able to do the following: `select get_config_parameter('ParameterName');`

I'm not sure if that is still available. There should also be a `set_config_parameter` function.

Comment: ok , i got it !! THX - yes i can use the get_cofig_parameter as well but i prefer creating a view of my own of the CONFIGURATION_PARAMETERS table and then play with it !! THX